# How can I create an unique list of data across columns containing text "Retailer Name"?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-arrays

I have certain data where I want the unique Retailer name across multiple sheets and multiple columns containing "Retailer Name" as the heading. I've shared the editable Google Sheet link, kindly help!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RM21N_w7mWTltMQi5Iq-p8iBaqJwegj94NwZVxfy5ng/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula combines the data from the "Gadget Sack", "Bloomindales" and "Legacy" sheets.

`=query(unique(flatten(query({'Gadget Shack'!A2:AC},"Select "&ArrayFormula(join(", ",text(query(transpose({column('Gadget Shack'!A2:AC2);mod(column('Gadget Shack'!A2:AC2)-column('Gadget Shack'!A2),3)}),"Select Col1 where Col2=0"),"Col0")))),query({Bloomingdales!A2:AC},"Select "&ArrayFormula(join(", ",text(query(transpose({column(Bloomingdales!A2:AC2);mod(column(Bloomingdales!A2:AC2)-column(Bloomingdales!A2),3)}),"Select Col1 where Col2=0"),"Col0")))),query({Legacy!A2:AC},"Select "&ArrayFormula(join(", ",text(query(transpose({column(Legacy!A2:AC2);mod(column(Legacy!A2:AC2)-column(Legacy!A2),3)}),"Select Col1 where Col2=0"),"Col0")))))),"select Col1 where Col1 is not null order by Col1")`

---

The formula consists of three elements:

- `query({'Gadget Shack'!A2:AC},"Select "&ArrayFormula(join(", ",text(query(transpose({column('Gadget Shack'!A2:AC2);mod(column('Gadget Shack'!A2:AC2)-column('Gadget Shack'!A2),3)}),"Select Col1 where Col2=0"),"Col0"))))`

  - returns every third column (the Retailer name)
  - build a query for each sheet
  - HT: infospired.com - [Dynamic Formula to Select Every nth Column in Query in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/select-every-nth-column-in-query-google-sheets/)
- `flatten (query, query, query)` output the result in a single column
- `unique` - get the unique values for the Retailer names
- `query("select Col1 where Col1 is not null order by Col1")` - remove the blank rows from the results and output the results in alpha order.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it's very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

`=unique(flatten(A2:A7,C2:C7,E2:E7))`

- `Flatten` consists of data from several columns and converts that data into a single column

---

**Sample Data**

[image: data]

---

**Output**

[image: output]

Comment: Is there an easier way to select "A:Z" where cell 1 contains "Retailer Name". Reason is there are too many columns which have the name "Retailer Name" and the data from sheets 2,3 and 4 will be merged in sheet 1. Maybe you'd get a clearer picture if I shared the whole sheet..

Comment: Try the other answer.